# Como mudar cor somente do cabeçalho css

Tags: html, css

Como faço pra mudar somente a cor do header e não do corpo inteiro do site? Já tentei colocando `background: #fff;` mas não dá certo.

Tentei isto, porem sem sucesso:

```
<header class="header">
    <h1> SAMCRO </h1>
    <h2> Sons of Anarchy </h2>
</header>

.header {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Carlos, edit sua resposta adicionando algum código, de preferência o `HTML` da página para que possamos te ajudar. Aproveite e faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) pelo StackOverflow pt.

Comment: Fiz exatamente como foi explicado, e simplesmente não dá certo aqui. Editei a pergunta e coloquei o código

Comment: Carlos, como você está declarando o CSS ? Está importando um arquivo para o HTML ou declarando direto na página ?

Comment: Testei seu código e funcionou. Se estiver declarando o CSS na página HTML, não esqueça de colocá-lo dentro das tags <style></style> Não esqueça também, que a cor que você está declarando é branco, ou seja, se seu background for branco, você não irá ver as alterações kk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto vai depender de como está estruturado seu HTML, com o código que você postou não há muito o que fazer a não ser supor que este `header` seja o primeiro filho direto em `body`.

Acredito que a forma mas fácil é atribuir um ID ao elemento. IDs são únicos no documento e pode ser usado neste caso, já que você está pretendendo definir regras que afetarão um único elemento. Algumas opções:

#### Definindo um id para o elemento

```css
#esse-header { background: red }
```

```html
<header id='esse-header' class="header">
    <h1> SAMCRO </h1>
    <h2> Sons of Anarchy </h2>
</header>

<header class="header">
    <h1> SAMCRO </h1>
    <h2> Sons of Anarchy </h2>
</header>

<header class="header">
    <h1> SAMCRO </h1>
    <h2> Sons of Anarchy </h2>
</header>
```

#### Pegando com [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afirst-child)

```css
header:first-child { background: red }
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <h1> SAMCRO </h1>
    <h2> Sons of Anarchy </h2>
</header>

<header class="header">
    <h1> SAMCRO </h1>
    <h2> Sons of Anarchy </h2>
</header>

<header class="header">
    <h1> SAMCRO </h1>
    <h2> Sons of Anarchy </h2>
</header>
```

#### Pegando por [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type)

```css
header:nth-of-type(1) { background: red }
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <h1> SAMCRO </h1>
    <h2> Sons of Anarchy </h2>
</header>

<header class="header">
    <h1> SAMCRO </h1>
    <h2> Sons of Anarchy </h2>
</header>

<header class="header">
    <h1> SAMCRO </h1>
    <h2> Sons of Anarchy </h2>
</header>
```

#### Pegando com [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child)

```css
header:nth-child(1) { background: red }
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <h1> SAMCRO </h1>
    <h2> Sons of Anarchy </h2>
</header>

<header class="header">
    <h1> SAMCRO </h1>
    <h2> Sons of Anarchy </h2>
</header>

<header class="header">
    <h1> SAMCRO </h1>
    <h2> Sons of Anarchy </h2>
</header>
```

Comment: Devemos nos lembrar que usar `Id`s não é uma boa pratica para definir estilos no HTML. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11167/26636. No entanto, foi uma boa resposta. :)

Answer (score 1):

Presumindo que seu `header` é a `tag` propriamente dita, leia sobre está `tag` do `HTML5` magnifica [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header).
A interação entre `HTML` e `CSS` permite que você adicione classes nas `tags` `HTML`, como por exemplo `<header class="uma-classe"></header>`, definindo uma classe, com `CSS`, você consegue manipular o estilo da mesma, esse estilo reflete na `tag`, consequentemente na página.

```css
.header {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <h1>Titulo do Cabeçalho</h1>
  </header>
  
  <section>
      <h2>Titulo de uma seção</h2>
      <p>Paragrafo de uma seção.</p>
  </section>
  
  <footer>
    <a href="#">Link no rodapé.</a>
  </footer>
</body>
```