# Exibir Div se nota for menor que 8

Tags: javascript

Como fazer um script, que se alguns destes 3 dropdowns a baixo for menor que 8 exibir uma div

```
  <select name="pes21" id="privileges1" class="" onclick="craateUserJsObject.ShowPrivileges();">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
   <select name="pes22" id="privileges1" class="" onclick="craateUserJsObject.ShowPrivileges();">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
   <select name="pes23" id="privileges1" class="" onclick="craateUserJsObject.ShowPrivileges();">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira é colocar uma classe para esses elementos, chamar uma função no `onchange`, assim você pega todos os elementos e percorre verificando se algum deles está com valor menor do 8 selecionado para exibir a div, exemplo:

```js
function privilegios(){
  
  elementos = document.getElementsByClassName('sel');
  
  for(i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++){
    
    var val = parseInt(elementos[i].value);
    
    if(val < 8 && !isNaN(val) ){
    document.getElementById('exibir').style.display = 'block';
      return;//encontrou um valor menor que 8, exibe a div e interrompe o loop
   } else {
    document.getElementById('exibir').style.display = 'none';
   }
    
  }
  

}
```

```css
#exibir{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<select name="pes21" id="privileges1" class="sel" onchange="privilegios()" >
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
   <select name="pes22" id="privileges1" class="sel" onchange="privilegios()">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
   <select name="pes23" id="privileges1" class="sel" onchange="privilegios()">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
        <div id="exibir">
        Exibiu a div
        </div>
```

OBS: Não se deve utilizar o mesmo id para vários elementos, `id="privileges1"`, ids são únicos para cada elemento. Para maiores informações [clique aqui.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11130/o-que-devo-usar-no-css-id-ou-classes)

Answer (score 0):

Segue o script usando jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  showDiv('.select');
  $('.select').on('change', function() {
    showDiv('.select');
  });
});

function showDiv(selector) {
  $(selector).each(function() {
    var display = ($(this).find('option[value != ""]').length < 9) ? 'show' : 'hide';
    $('#divTexto')[display]();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="pes21" id="privileges1" class="select">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<select name="pes22" id="privileges1" class="select">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<select name="pes23" id="privileges1" class="select">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```