# Layout de caixa de texto

Tags: html, css, layout

Estou tentando fazer algo como aqueles elementos de forums, que mostram uma div com uma foto do usuário e um espaço com algum texto a direita, sabe?
Já tentei posicionar um do lado do outo usando o *float* mas a parte do texto ficou torta... Tipo... Não ficou centralizada dentro da sua parte no contender.

```css
.spe-layout {
    height: 210px;
    border-left: 1px solid #4774c6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4774c6;
    border-right: 1px solid #4774c6;
}

.spe-layout h1 {
    background-color: #4774c6;
    color: white;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#Dq {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#parte-user {
    align-self: flex-start;
}

#foto {
    background-color: #010000;
    height: 110px;
    width: 110px;
}
```

```html
<section id="Dq" class="spe-layout">
  <h1>Título</h1>
  <div id="parte-user">
    <h3>Gabriel</h3>
    <div id="foto">Foto</div>
  </div>
  <span>Texto</span>
</section>
```

Comment: Poste o código daquilo que você já tem até agora

Comment: Coloquei ai em cima.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tentei organizar o código de outra maneira - Removi `id`'s e susbsituí por `classes` com o pensamento que estes "Cartões de Usuário" irão ser utilizados em mais sítios, e tentei também de certa forma minimizar o código.

Quando um elemento se repete várias vezes num documento (na mesma página), devemos usar `classes` e não `id`'s, porque `id`'s são apenas para ser usados uma vez só em todo o documento. Mais sobre isto [neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11130/11886).

```css
.userContainer {
    border: 1px solid #4774c6;
}
h1.userHeader {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #4774c6;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 10px;
}
.userPicture {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 16px!important;
}
.clear {clear:both;} /* Limpa/remove os floats */
```

```html
<div class="userContainer">
    <h1 class="userHeader">Alexis Cooper</h1>
    <img class="userPicture" src="http://lorempixel.com/110/110/people/1/" width="110" height="110">
    <p class="userInfo">
        Random text about Alexis - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur vulputate eget tellus ut sodales.
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div> <!-- Evita que elementos que venham a seguir peguem o float anteriormente atribuído acima. [Veja CSS] -->
</div>
```

Comment: Não era isto que você queria @Dongabi ?