# Como formatar todos os labels de um form com um estilo associado a um id?

Tags: html, css

Tinha este exemplo inicialmente:

css

```css
#label1 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align:left;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

html

```html
...
<table>  
  <tr>
        <td><label for="nome1" id="label1">Jogador 1</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="nome1" id="nome1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="nome2" id="label1">Jogador 2</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="nome2" ></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td><label for="nome3" id="label1">Jogador 3</label></td>                            
        <td><input type="text" name="nome3" id="nome3" ></td>
        ...            
</table>
```

Naturalmente esbarrei-me na repetição dos ids apesar de funcionar.
Para solucionar o problema alterei os id para label1, label2, label3 ...

```css
#label1, label2, label3, label4 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align:left;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Neste cenário, apenas o label mencionado em primeiro lugar (label1) sofre a formatação.
O que estou a fazer errado neste cenário?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc tem que colocar o <kbd>#</kbd> na frente de todos os `ids` no CSS. Para vc entender melho pq o seu CSS não funcionou eu escreve ele diferente, colocando um `ID` em cada linha, como sugere o próprio manual da Google por exemplo https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html#Selector_and_Declaration_Separation:

```
#label1, 
#label2, 
#label3, 
#label4 {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align:left;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Agora fica mais fácil de vc notar a necessidade de coloca o kbd>#  na frente do nome de cada `id` Essa outra questão sobre `ID` pode te interessar tem várias coisas interessantes lá [Por que é considerado errado/ruim repetir uma ID em HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/318255/por-que-%C3%A9-considerado-errado-ruim-repetir-uma-id-em-html/318268#318268)

---

Agora sobre o que eu te sugiro e não usar o `ID` para colocar estilo em elementos. Eu te sugiro colocar *classes*, mesmo que o elemento já tenha um `ID`, pois `IDs` são únicos e como vc viu vc precisa declarar no CSS `4 ids` para usar o mesmo estilo, e com a `.classe` vc só precisa de uma `.classe` que será aplicada nas `labels`. Aqui tem uma questão que tb vale a pena vc parar para ler, vai te ajudar pro resto da vida de dev: [O que devo usar no CSS, id ou class?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11130/o-que-devo-usar-no-css-id-ou-class)

Então vc teria algo assim:

```css
.class-label {
    color: #FF0000;
    text-align:left;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label class="class-label" for="nome1" id="label1">Jogador 1</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="nome1" id="nome1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label class="class-label" for="nome2" id="label1">Jogador 2</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="nome2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label class="class-label" for="nome3" id="label1">Jogador 3</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="nome3" id="nome3"></td>
        ...
</table>
```

---

**DICA**

Essa parte é apenas uma dica, apenas outros métodos para vc pegar todas as labels, mas já adianto que para usa-los vc precisa saber exatamente o que está fazendo ou pode ter problemas de hierarquia de classes, conflitos de classes, etc...

Essa definição no CSS pega todas as `label` que estão dentro de uma `table`

```
table label {
    color: #FF0000;
    text-align:left;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Essa definição pega todas as `label` que tenho um atributo `ID` independente do nome do `ID`

```
label[id] {
    color: #ff0;
    text-align:left;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

E essa definição pega todas as `labels` do documento.

```
label {
    color: #ff0;
    text-align:left;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Mas como falei, antes de sair usando o CSS dessa maneira leia o manual que citei no início da resposta, e leia tb os outros links, vão te ajudar muito. Sobre hierarquia de classes vc DEVE ler isso: [Qual seletor css tem prioridade?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/143850/qual-seletor-css-tem-prioridade)